# Let $\pi: E \to M$ a vector bundle. Is $E$ a direct summnad of $M\times\mathbb{R}^{d}$, for some $d$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $\pi: E \to M$ a vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$.

$E$ is direct summand of $M\times\mathbb{R}^{d}$, if there exist a vector bundle morphisms $f:E\to M\times\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $h:M\times\mathbb{R}^{d}\to E$ such that $\pi_{1}\circ f =Id_{M}$,$\pi\circ h= Id_{M}$ and $h\circ f=Id_{E}$.

Comment: Yes.  Look up the homotopy-classification of vector bundles.  There is something called a tautological bundle over a Grassman manifold.  You are describing the operation of taking the pull-back of a map $M \to Gr_{d,m}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Proposition 1.4 in Hatcher's book [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf).

Comment: Note that the base is assumed to be compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @ZhenLin: True, but there is a minor modification of the argument that does the job whenever the base is paracompact with finite covering dimension (the same argument as for existence of an embedding of manifolds into $R^n$): Hatcher was lazy here assuming compactness.